# Is it possible to match templated base in template specializations?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I could of course use `is_base` if the base class where not a template.  However, when it is, I just don't see any way to generically match any derived type.  Here's a basic example of what I mean:

```
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>

template < typename T >
struct test_base
{
};

template < typename T >
struct check : boost::mpl::false_ {};

template < typename T >
struct check<test_base<T> > : boost::mpl::true_ {};

struct test_derived : test_base<int> {};

#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
  std::cout << check<test_derived>::value << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
}
```

I want that to return `true_` rather than `false_`.  The real example has like 7 template parameters, most defaulted, and uses Boost.Parameter to refer to them by name.  In order to use `is_base` I'd have to be able to pull the parameters out somehow and I don't see a way to do that short of declaring internal typedefs.

I think it's impossible.  Looking to be proven wrong.

Comment: can you introduce unique tag type into test base and disable/enable based on that?

Comment: That's a viable option I should have thought of myself.  Still interested if anyone can find a way around without it though.

Comment: @aaa - you should make that an answer.  Have a feeling it's the only possible method so in a couple days after I get no answer you may as well get credit for it.

Comment: maybe I will wait couple day, someone experienced may be looking for unanswered questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tweak your test a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>

template < typename T >
struct test_base
{
};

template < typename T >
struct check_
{
    template<class U>
    static char(&do_test(test_base<U>*))[2];
    static char(&do_test(...))[1];
    enum { value = 2 == sizeof do_test(static_cast<T*>(0)) };
};

template < typename T >
struct check : boost::mpl::bool_<check_<T>::value> {};

struct test_derived : test_base<int> {};

int main()
{
  std::cout << check<test_derived>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  SFINAE to the rescue yet again.

Comment: SFINAE is not involved here, just pure function overloading. I.e. instantiating do_test(test_base<U>*) never produces an error.